# get response or signal when all threads are complete

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4

Using GUI i am copying multiple files. for each file i am starting a thread. Is there is a way with which I can get a signal or response which tells that all the threads are done with their work. I need the response because depending on the response when all threads are done, I want to enable/disable few buttons and check boxes on the GUI.

```
for file_name in _src_files:
    if (os.path.exists(_full_file_name)):
        t = Thread(target=file_util.copy_file, args=[_full_file_name, _str_destination_dir, 'update=1'])
        t.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a class that inherits from `QObject` and have custom signals, for example:

```
def copy_file(source, destination, message, log):
    [...]
    log.finished.emit()
```

---

```
class Logger(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
```

---

```
self.l = Logger()
for file_name in _src_files:
    if (os.path.exists(_full_file_name)):
        t = Thread(target=file_util.copy_file, args=[_full_file_name, _str_destination_dir, 'update=1'], self.l)
        t.start()
self.l.finished.connect(some_slot)
```

Example:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Logger(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(str)

def myfunc(i, log):
    print("sleeping 5 sec from thread %d" % i)
    time.sleep(5)
    print("finished sleeping from thread %d" % i)
    log.finished.emit("message %d" % i)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.l = Logger()
        self.counter_threads = 0
        for i in range(10):
            t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(i, self.l))
            t.start()
            self.counter_threads += 1
        self.l.finished.connect(self.some_slot)

    def some_slot(self, message):
        print("some_slot: "+ message)
        self.counter_threads -= 1
        if self.counter_threads == 0:
            print("finished all threads")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thnx for reply. As I am new to python, i need clarification that when after loop i call self.l.finished.connect(some_slot), as you said, it will run some_slot only once when all threads are finished, or it will be called after each thread is finished. Secondly some_slot could be a function of same class? thanks

Comment: **First:** It will be executed every time you call `emit()`, that is to say for each thread, according to your comment you indicate that you want to pass a result, if so, what kind of result is it? **Second:** some_slot can be a member of the class.

Comment: I actually supposed to emit only when the last thread is finished. So  I can know from the emit that all the threads are done

Comment: In general I think that all threads do not do the same work, because for example one thread can copy more information than another, consequently the thread that starts first does not necessarily end first, but if you want to know if all threads have finished the solution is simple: use a counter. In a moment I will show you an example.

Comment: @latlong I already update my answer, if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: thanx, it helped. BTW can we define Logger class in a separate file